# Rails 5 Deprecation Warning "The behavior of `attribute_change`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1, deprecation-warning

I'm attempting to upgrade to Rails 5.1.0 from 4.2 and getting this error while running my Rspec test suite.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes.keys` instead. (called from has_changes? at /Users/djohnson/projects/EvantaAccessAPI/app/models/user.rb:280)
```

I've checked out a few similar Stackoverflow questions but none seemed to quite match my scenario. I'm using elasticsearch and chewy and have this line in my user.rb model.

```
update_index('users') { self if has_changes? }
```

Which calls the `has_changes?` method below:

```
def has_changes?
  changes.empty? || (changes.keys & %w(first_name last_name title organization_name)).present?
end
```

What is the best way to refactor this to maintain existing functionality and remove these deprecation warnings?

Thanks!

Comment: The warning message seems to outline exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks @MarsAtomic I pretty much thought that myself but some on the content of that deprecation message led me to want to get a second opinion. The "(e.g. the opposite of what it returns now)" made me nervous. But everything worked and continues to work. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the method's body to

```
saved_changes.empty? || (saved_changes.keys & %w(first_name last_name title organization_name)).present?
```

and it seems to be working the same but without the million deprecation warnings.

It seems the same goes for `changed?` which now prefers to be called `saved_changes?`